# Same code, same browser, same webserver but still things look different

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, tomcat

I'm developing a website which should be running on an apache tomcat webserver and i'm having some styling isues. When i load the page on tomcat on my laptop en i open it in IE, everything looks fine. Firefox looks fine. I upload the site to our company server (also running tomcat, same version), Firefox still looks good, but in IE some items look deformed. It's not that the css is not loaded at all, because background, boldness on some fields etc. look fine. But for instance:

```
 .input-lblue {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #E1ECF2;
  border-style: none;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

makes an input field of this class 100% width, with bold tekst, as expected, however the background ain't blue when running on the company server and with IE. How is this possible?

The apache tomcat version i'm using is 7.0.42 and IE is version 10.0.9200.16660
Laptop is running on window 7 64-bit, company server is running on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.9 (Tikanga)

Comment: Are you certain this isn't a caching problem in IE?

Comment: Can you run Fiddler or similar to check if there's any 404's or 500's ? Is it possible different html is being rendered in the different environments ? What about caching ? Are media files being loaded from a different hostname (i.e. a CDN) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have experienced an issue like this before. Double check that IE isn't forcing itself into Compatibility View: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/use-compatibility-view#ie=ie-10

Sometimes personal or corporate settings can cause IE to always render a particular domain using an older IE engine in Compatibility View.

Comment: Thanks. There was a setting saying that intranet websites should allways be displayed in compatibility mode.